# Android - Display Progress Dialog on button click

Tags: jquery, android, html, jquery-ui

I have to display the progress image during button onclick function. Here is my jquery code snippet:

```
    $( function() {
    $('#loginButton').click(function() {
         db = openDatabase("DBNAME", "1.0", "DBNAME", 200000);

             createAndroidMetadataTable();
             insertAndroidMetadataTable();
        function reachableCallback(reachability) {
            // There is no consistency on the format of reachability
            var networkState = reachability.code || reachability;

            var states = {};
            states[NetworkStatus.NOT_REACHABLE]                      = 'No network connection';
            states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_CARRIER_DATA_NETWORK] = 'Carrier data connection';
            states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_WIFI_NETWORK]         = 'WiFi connection';

            alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        }   

    });

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

} );
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
<h1>Download Data</h1> 
<div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
      Email: <input type="text" name="userid" id="useridBox" value="" data-theme="a" /> 
     Password: <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwdBox" value="" data-theme="a" />
     <button type="submit" data-theme="a" id="loginButton">Login</button> 

</div>
```

In the above HTML div tag i have to display the progress image while the user logs in. Please help me with the code in login button function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some of the masking plugins or write the cutom code for it simplest way is masking plugin like block UI . Here is the sample

[Jquery BlockUI Sample on click](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element)